# Best way to implement a matrix (metro stations / metro lines)

Tags: java, matrix, implementation

I'm developing a small web application in Java that given a London geolocation it finds the nearest metro station and its respective lines. I'm trying to find the best way to represent the metroStation - metroLines relation. As you know one metro station can be part of several lines. What I'm doing right now is that I have a table in my database with the relation represented as a matrix. Something like this:

```
stationId | blueLine | blackLine | pinkLine | purpleLine | ... | greenLine
    25          0          1          1           0                  1
```

Where those 0 and 1 are booleans meaning that the station is part of that metro line (not nullable and with 0 as default). Of course this data won't change very often (they don't build new stations or lines very often) and I think a call to the database every time I need this data (which is a lot) is kind of overkill. I know one solution could be to cache it but I've been thinking if a Java approach for storing these kind of data is better for me: Maybe a constant list of metro objects, some sort of static class with all the metro stations data inside, use a bean class and inject it using dependency injection...

I'd like your opinion, what do you think is the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: PS: There could be for example, 200 metro stations and 10 metro lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I really had to hold all my objects in memory, I would create a Map for each kind of Query I would need:

One

```
HashMap<Line, List<Station>>
```

and one

```
HashMap <Station, List<Line>>
```

for instance. This way your queries would be rather fast and since the Maps store the pointers of the objects this wouldn't take up that much more space.

In the end you could create a singleton class that acts as your 'data access layer', offering a fixed set of query methods to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with something similar to what Simon suggested. I have:

```
HashMap<MetroLine, List<MetroStation>> hmMetroLines;
EnumSet<MetroStation> esMetroStations;
```

Where MetroStation is a Enum with all the data of the lines it belongs. Something like this:

```
public enum MetroStation{
METRO1(1, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
        false, false, false, false, false, false, "descirption1"),
METRO2(2, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
        false, false, false, false, false, false, "description2"),...

private int id;
private boolean line1;
private boolean line2;
private boolean line3;
...
private boolean line14;
private String description;
```

I use a Singleton class as suggested by Simon, creating the HashMap and the Set only once.